# How to change priority of predefined warning

Tags: configuration, findbugs

The warning [`DE_MIGHT_IGNORE`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DE_MIGHT_IGNORE) is judged as a Low priority message by FindBugs. How can I change the config to treat `DE_MIGHT_IGNORE` as a high priority message?
Using Maven and Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familar with FindBugs internals but [as far as I see in the source code](https://code.google.com/p/findbugs/source/browse/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/DroppedException.java#270) priority is decided at runtime and affected by various conditions. Unfortunately I have not found any way to change the priority of FindBugs warnings.

A workaround which we use is ignoring FindBugs' priority and creating separate FindBugs configurations (with different [include and exclude filters](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)) for our priorities. We have a `FindBugs-HighPrio` Jenkins job and a `FindBugs-Others` job for everything else.